# How to access a list element within a Hashmap?

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I am saving data into a `Hashmap`, with a `String` being the `key` and a `List` being the value. How would I be able to access a specific element in the value `List`?

**For example**:

I want to access the element at index 5 within the values `List`.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `map.get("key").get(5)`!?

Comment: @gokareless it is just too basic, OP has not spent a couple of weeks / months of learning java, there was no actual research before posting => downvote!

Comment: @luk2302 now that's makes sence for the author, or at least it should've :-) Thanks!

Comment: @luk2302 thanks, that worked. I have only been doing java for two weeks and I did try and do research into this but it looks like i was googling the wrong thing

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over keys by calling map.entrySet().

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    List<String> list = entry.getValue();
    
    // get value
    list.get(5);
}
```

Comment: You *can* do that, but I'm not sure it was what the OP was wanting to do?